# Linked List in C

Tags: c, data-structures, singly-linked-list

I am practicing linked lists in c, I want to store characters in the nodes using rand, but the last letter is repeated in the list, can anyone see what happens?

with this function I fill the nodes:

```
nodo* nodoListas(nodo*Lista){
    int i;
    char *elemento, caracter;
    srand (time(NULL));
    for (i = 0; i< CANT_NODOS; i++){
        caracter = /*(char*)*/(65 +rand()% 25);
        elemento = &caracter;
        Lista = agregarNodo (Lista, elemento);
    }
}
```

and this is the function agregarNodo:

```
nodo* agregarNodo (nodo* Lista, char* elemento){
    nodo* nuevoNodo, *aux;
    nuevoNodo = (nodo*) malloc (sizeof(nodo));
    nuevoNodo -> elemento = elemento;
    nuevoNodo -> siguiente = NULL;
    if(Lista == NULL){
        Lista = nuevoNodo;
    }
    else{
        aux = Lista; //para no perder el elemento
        while(aux->siguiente != NULL){
                aux = aux -> siguiente;             
            }
        aux-> siguiente = nuevoNodo;
    }
    return Lista;
}
```

here is the code I'm doing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define CANT_NODOS 5

typedef struct Nodo{
    char* elemento;
    struct Nodo* siguiente; /*vinculo para unir mas nodos*/
}nodo;

//funcion que genera o crea una lista
nodo* ListaElementos(nodo* Lista){
    Lista = NULL ;
    return Lista;
}

// funcion que agrega nodos a la lista 

nodo* agregarNodo (nodo* Lista, char* elemento){
    nodo* nuevoNodo, *aux;
    nuevoNodo = (nodo*) malloc (sizeof(nodo));
    nuevoNodo -> elemento = elemento;
    nuevoNodo -> siguiente = NULL;
    if(Lista == NULL){
        Lista = nuevoNodo;
    }
    else{
        aux = Lista; //para no perder el elemento
        while(aux->siguiente != NULL){
                aux = aux -> siguiente;             
            }
        aux-> siguiente = nuevoNodo;
    }
    return Lista;
}
//Funcion que libera la memoria
void LiberarLista (nodo* Lista ){   

    free (Lista);
}

nodo* Lista1;
nodo* Lista2;

nodo* nodoListas(nodo*Lista){
    int i;
    char *elemento, caracter;
    srand (time(NULL));
    for (i = 0; i< CANT_NODOS; i++){
        caracter = /*(char*)*/(65 +rand()% 25);
        elemento = &caracter;
        Lista = agregarNodo (Lista, elemento);
    }
}

int main(void){
    Lista1 = ListaElementos(Lista1);
    Lista2 = ListaElementos(Lista2);
    Lista1 = nodoListas(Lista1);

//impresion Lista 1
    while (Lista1 != NULL){
        printf("%s\t", Lista1->elemento);
        Lista1 = Lista1 -> siguiente;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do:

```
caracter = /*(char*)*/(65 +rand()% 25);
elemento = &caracter;
```

You are writing the new random value in the memory space declared as caracter, then putting a pointer (elemento) to this memory space.
But you are always using the same memory space caracter in all the for loop.
So you are always writing at the same place and pointing to the same place, and just updating its value, hence the repetition of the last character value.

Comment: You could try to declare an array of caracters instead and fill each of the values then point to it

Answer (score 0):

you are pointing to same memory always in your code

```
caracter = /*(char*)*/(65 +rand()% 25);
elemento = &caracter;
```

you can use

```
    caracter=malloc(sizeof(char));
    *caracter = /*(char*)*/(65 +rand()% 25);
    //sleep(1);
    elemento = caracter;
```

by the way You should use array of characters here